# Adding fields to existing model doesn't work in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I have already created own model with OneToOneField with User-model. Now, I want to add field to that model, but doing `manage.py makemigrations` and `migrate` doesn't see any changes, which I made to my `models.py`.

**`models.py`:**

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    footsize = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    headsize = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    handsize = models.CharField(max_length=100) #field what I want to add

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.id, self.footsize, self.headsize)
```

If I try to add values to handsize with shell, I get an error that the handsize field doesn't exists. What's the problem?

Comment: is this the first migration for this app?

Comment: have you added the app in django settings under `installed_apps` ?

Comment: @r3ign Yes, I have

Comment: @Sayse No, I have done them before.

Comment: what command are you using for makemigrations ? can you paste it here.

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib sudo python manage.py makemigrations

Comment: Have you got the order confused? it's `makemigrations` first and `migrate` second.

Comment: I know that, I just had it in wrong order in question, so I'll edit it.

Comment: just make sure when you run the makemigration command, there should be a new created migration file in the migrations folder. Also try running makemigrations using appname. Are you using virtualenv for your project. ?

Comment: Also specify the python and django versions

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib Yes, I get a migration file, where is the model **without** the new field. Same happens, if I remove the file and make migrations again. I don't use virtualenv. Python 2.7.10 and Django 1.9.5.

Comment: Ensure that you have migrations folder with \_\_init__.py file in it.

Comment: @AlexT Yes, I have. It's empty though, but I think it should be(?)

Comment: you have a new migration file when you run makemigration, What is the message on the console when you run migrate command ?

Comment: @MMakela yes, it is. Add you migration file snippet here https://gist.github.com/

Comment: @AlexT Here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/250ac6c78a906332e6fa14086196f645

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib `Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: index, sessions, admin, axes, auth, contenttypes
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested to do same thing as in my question with my backup. Terminal show this message, when doing `makemigrations`:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'handsize' to userdetails without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

I'm sure, that I answered earlier with 1), so that's why field didn't show in the database. So, now I answered 2) and added default value to the field:

```
    handsize = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='40')
```

Now `migrate` works and adds handsize as a new field to database.

Answer (score -1):

When you said that you have already created model, I assume that you ran initial migrations. So, when running migrations again after putting in new fields, you can't run blanket migrations. You will have to specify app name after makemigrations. Something like this.

```
./manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

and the

```
./manage.py migrate.
```

Should work.